# Error on Correlated Sub Query. "MultiPart ID oh.SalesOrderID could not be bound"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Today I discussed with some colleagues this question and we can't have a solid argument why this doesn't work, we just know that it don't.

Can someone give me a solid explanation?

This is the query:

```
select oh.*,
        test.*
 from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as oh, ( 
                                          select *
                                          from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as od
                                          where oh.SalesOrderID = od.SalesOrderID
                                      ) as test;
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I guess none of your colleagues are very familiar with SQL, because a correlated subquery is simply not allowed in that context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you cannot put correlated subqueries in the `FROM` clause using `JOIN` syntax.

Second, when you use `,`, it affects the scoping of the aliases.

You probably intend:

```
select oh.*, test.*
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh cross apply
     (select *
      from Sales.SalesOrderDetail od
      where oh.SalesOrderID = od.SalesOrderID
     ) test;
```

You can readily phrase this as a `join` as well:

```
select oh.*, od.*
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh join
     Sales.SalesOrderDetail od
     on oh.SalesOrderID = od.SalesOrderID;
```

This is the most natural way to write the logic as a SQL query.

Your syntax is reminiscent of the Postgres syntax for a lateral join (which is what `apply` does).  In Postgres, this would be:

```
select oh.*, test.*
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh, lateral
     (select *
      from Sales.SalesOrderDetail od
      where oh.SalesOrderID = od.SalesOrderID
     ) test;
```

Comment: Thanks. Two question. Can you give two technical answers about these 2 topics? 1) Why technically SQL Server doesn't allow me this "First, you cannot put correlated subqueries in the FROM clause using JOIN syntax."; 2) It affects how? "Second, when you use ,, it affects the scoping of the aliases." Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Tito . . . SQL Server does not allow it because it has never been a part of the SQL language.  Never.  The `,` "groups" the fields as well as does a `cross join`.  You cannot reference the first table in an `on` clause in the second part.  But, since you should never use commas in the `from` clause (well, it is okay for a lateral join in Postgres or a `cross join` in MS Access), this is not an issue.